Stripe CLI force live mode when running Webhooks integration
I'm following the steps described on Stripe Webohooks docs to setup a local server and test my Webhooks integration. The steps are simple

Create and run a node server using Stripe test API key
Install and login to Stripe CLI
Run stripe listen --forward-to localhost:4242/webhook to listen for Webhooks events
Trigger the target Webhooks, in my case stripe trigger charge.dispute.created

The steps are pretty simple, but when I try to run the last step, it outputs the following exception:
Trigger failed: Request failed, status=400, body={
  "error": {
    "message": "You cannot use the test ID 'pm_card_createDisputeInquiry' in livemode. If you are testing your integration, please use your testmode API keys instead.",
    "param": "payment_method",
    "request_log_url": "https://dashboard.stripe.com/logs/req_IF0F0YgB7954el?t=1722687021",
    "type": "invalid_request_error"
  }
}

Just like if I was using the CLI in live mode. I already tried running both stripe login and stripe listen using the flag --api-key and sending my test api key but the result is the same. I have no idea why the CLI is using live mode, I just can't test the Webhooks in test mode.
I can confirm that live mode is being used because I can see in Stripe dashboard my computer as a registered local listener as well as the temporary restricted keys that the CLI is automatically creating.
OBS: Yes, I'm using the test key in the node server application. No production key is being used in the entire process.

Looks like your Stripe CLI is logged into the live mode. Could you try logging in with interactive mode and ensure test mode secret key (sk_test_xxx) us used?

Interactive login in Stripe CLI will be: stripe login --interactive

@yuting I tried both --interactive and --api-key, none of them worked

Having same problem. Did you find a solution?

Unfortunately no… I gave up
